# Grails 3.3.8 no recarga los cambios efectuados en el proyecto

Tags: grails

Tengo un proyecto con grails 3.3.8, el problema es que una vez que edito un controlador o un archivo gsp, los cambios no se ven reflejados en el navegador web a pesar de que sí aparece el siguiente mensaje cuando detecta un cambio:

```
Controller.groovy change, compiling...
```

Para correr la aplicación solamente ejecuto el comando `run-app`, no sé si me falta colocar algún parámetro o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Si abres esa misma página en modo incógnito ves reflejados los cambios?

Comment: Tampoco se ven reflejados los cambios.

Comment: Estás seguro de que modificaste el archivo correcto?

Comment: Sí, revisé todos los archivos que modifiqué pero nunca noté los cambios.

Comment: Por si a alguien le sirve solamente hay que poner la carpeta de proyectos en el disco local c, algo como c:\proyectosgrails\proyecto (en el caso de windows.)

Ya que si ponía la carpeta en otra carpeta como documentos no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

sinceramente no tengo tu solución porque yo he desarrollado siempre desde el editor atom, sublime y Notepad. Simplemente tengo integrado el framework a mi Sistema Operativo, así como el jdk y lo ejecuto desde cmd, como tengo xamp instalado ocupa el server tomcat de éste.

Cuando me sucede eso simplemente detengo la ejecución y la levanto de nuevo y con eso se actualiza. Sinó logra levantar es que se emiten errores generados por los últimos cambios... O por la falta de recursos, como por ejemplo que se corte el enlace a datos, aunque eso seria muy raro.
Habrá que revisar tu log.